# Magento 2 Add Custom Dynamic Link in Customer Navigation

Tags: layout, customer-account, magento2.2.2, navigation

I can't figure it out how to add links dynamically to customer navigation.

this is my xml:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
   <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Custom\Link\" name="block">
       <action method="addCustomLink">
        <!--  HERE DYNAMICALLY NEEDS TO ADD ARGUMENTS e.g label, path etc..-->
       </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Block:

```
class Link extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current
{
  public function addCustomLink() 
   {
    $parent = $this->getParentBlock();

            $parent->addLink(
                'Dynamic Label goes here',
                'Dynamic Url goes here',
                'Dynamic title goes here'
         );
   }
}
```

This is giving me error: `Invalid method Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation::addLink` .

Anybody have any suggestion how could one do this?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Prakash Thapa  this worked perfectly for me no need anything else in block

`protected function _toHtml()
    {
        return '<li class="nav item"><a href="test">TEST</a></li>';
    }`

Answer (score 2):

In app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml you can add following line:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Custom\Link"
                   name="test-customer-account-navigation-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">DYNAMIC TEXT NED TO DISPLAY</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">DYNAMIC YOUR_PATH_URL(like: customer/account ) </argument>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">240</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

**Update**

Then,app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Block/Custom/Link.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Custom;

class Link extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link
{
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->setPath($path);
    }

    public function setLabel($label)
    {
        $this->setLabel($label);
    }
/** 
 * you can directly change href also like this;
 * if you use getHref() then setPath() will be ignored
 *
 * @return string
 */
 public function getHref()
 {
    return 'https://www.google.com/';
 }

}
```

It should work.

Comment: this is exactly what I Can't have just read the question `label` `path` needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks That's almost perfect but it fall short as the link doesn't have the css classes `nav item`  is there something else needs to do?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question. Thanks

Comment: Sorry if that wans't clear I've update my question with screen shoot.

Comment: Please add your label with   $this->setLabel("HERE IS YOUR LABEL");

Comment: there are no issue with label it's with css class